# Anybody knows about ACTION_RF_FIELD_ON_DETECTED?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, nfc, broadcast, android-broadcast

I want to use this broadcast intent to start my activity as soon as my mobile enters NFC reader's field? Please help if anybody ever done this....

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but not recommended to do this.

First off, the ACTION_RF_FIELD_ON_DETECTED is a protected intent. To be able to receive it you have to white-list your application in the etc/nfcee_access.xml file. This file grants access to the secure element, so it is not writable on non rooted phones.

Second: The ACTION_RF_FIELD_ON_DETECTED event is not reliable. This is stated in the source-code and true in praxis. You simply don't get such the intent every time the phone senses an RF field (has technical/historical reasons that I won't explain here in detail).

If you can work around these two problems, you can just list ACTION_RF_FIELD_ON_DETECTED in your manifest and Android will happily start your application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply....I have rooted Nexus S and also listed my app in the whitelist....have you tried this kind of thing before?

Comment: ACTION_RF_FIELD_ON_INTENDED ?? whats that??